# Prove that $\int\limits_0^1|f_n(x)-g_n(x)|dx\leq\int\limits_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f,g:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. And $f(t)=g(t)=0$ for all $t\in(1,2]$.
Define $$f_n(x)= n\int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)dt \quad \text{and} \quad g_n(x)= n\int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{n}}g(t)dt$$
Prove that:

$1$. $\int\limits_0^1|f_n(x)-g_n(x)|dx\leq\int\limits_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx$

$2$. If $g$ is continuous then $g_n\to g$ uniformly

$3$. If $f$ is integrable, then $\int\limits_0^1|f_n-f|dt\to0$

**I am allowed to use the following without a proof:**

$``\forall~\epsilon>0,$ there exists a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int\limits_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx<\epsilon"$

**My attempt:**

1. $$\int\limits_0^1|f_n(x)-g_n(x)|dx= \int\limits_0^1| n\int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)-g(t)dt|\leq\int\limits_0^1 n\int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{n}}|f(t)-g(t)|dt$$
   So if I can take the $|f(t)-g(t)|$ portion out side the first integral, then we have the result.  Bu I don't see a proper method to do that.

For parts $2$ and $3$ I really cannot adopt a correct method. Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** For $x\in [0,1]$, write $f_n(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^1 k_n(t-x) f(t) d t$ where
\begin{equation}
k_n(u) =
\left\{
\begin{array}\cr
n  \text{ if } 0\le u < 1/n\cr
0  \text{ otherwise}\cr
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}